# Ajax response in tornado some questions about the usage of the self.write

Tags: jquery, ajax, tornado

I am still not familiar with the tornado and I am very sorry if there is an obvious answer about the question^_^.

I want to get a response from the tornado to the js using the self.write.But when I use the self.write,of course the response is passed to the js but the website will go to a new page with the message of the response on it.I don't want this happens but I don't know how to deal with it.
For example

```
class IndexHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
''' handler the "/" action '''
def get(self):
    self.render("index.html")

def post(self):
    name = self.get_argument("name", "None")
    n = "123"
    print name
    if name != n :
        self.write("F")
        print "index1"
    else:
        self.write("T")
        print "index2"
```

and there is the js

```
$("p").css("display", "none");

$(document).ready(function() {
$("#myButton").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $.post("/", {name: $("#name").val()}, function(data) {

            if (data === "F") {
                $("p").css("display", "block");
                alert(data);
            } else {
                $.get("/person");
                alert(data);
            }
    });
});
});
```

when data === "F", it will work.But immediately the page turns to a page with only the data on it.I don't want this happens.How can I handle it?

I am sorry that I forget to post the html code.
Here is the code in the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
</head>

<body>
    <form method="post" id="myForm">
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name">
        <input type="submit" id="myButton" name="button">
    </form>
    <p>inform!</p>

    <script type="text/javascript" src={{ static_url("index.js") }}>      </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use preventDefault() call to prevent page redirect:

```
$("#myButton").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post("/", {name: $("#name").val()}, function(data) {
        if (data === "F") {
            $("p").css("display", "block");
            alert(data);
        } else {
            $.get("/person");
            alert(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I delete the "method:post" in the form and then have tried your way,but there is still something wrong.First,when I debug,I click the "button" and it will first go to the the line of "$.post...",but it will not go into the function but jump to the line of "e.stopPropagation()".Then it go into the function above.Second,it seems like that after I use it,the url shows that it runs to a get method,for the url is "localhost:8000/name=123&button=xxx"

Comment: Sorry, seems that I missed something, I've edited answer, please try it anew.

Comment: I've tried again.I have a question about whether I should set the method in form,for if i don't set the method,it seems that the method will be set "get" as default.In this case,the stopPropagation() doesn't work for after the execution in js,page will refresh and url turns into "localhost:8000/name=123&button=xxx".  And I tried again,adding "method='post'"in the form.This time,when i input 123 in text,the page redirect to "/person",which is what I expect.But when I tried other strings,js codes run good,but after all js execution,the page turns blank with "F" on it,which I don't want happen.

Comment: I feel like it is close to the Answer!!!But there is a problem that using the preventDefault,the $.get("/person") in the else doesn't work ><

Comment: I forgot about get, sorry, I've edited answer again.

Comment: After the submit,the page turns blank with only "T" or "F" on it.QAQ.preventDefault seems not work.

Comment: The `preventDefault` needs to be earlier, before the `$.post`. `$.post` is an asynchronous function, but for `preventDefault` to be effective it must be within the synchronous scope of the event handler (i.e. in the first `function`, not the second)

Comment: @Eugene Soldatov, thanks.After modifying the preventDefault,I also replace the '$.get("/person")' with ' window.location.href="\person" ' and resolved it finally.There might be something wrong with the .get function in this case,it just looks well in the console but the page not redirect.